# using sphinx, is it possible to update record without reindexing with killlist

Tags: sphinx

as title describes, when I update a record in database,then I want to update sphinx index, is it possible to do so without reindexing with killlist?

Answer (score 1):

Well can use RT - Real-Time - indexes. These manage the kill-list internally for you (ie its abstracted away).

If using a main+delta (ie killlist on the delta) then the only way to update the killlist attached to the delta is to reindex it.